# Why phpMyAdmin throws an error when running on XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am a PHP beginner. I currently created a todo-list website which required MySQL. I installed XAMPP and attempted to run my project. I tried to start the server, at first I found that the IIS is already at the default port position 3306, so I made it at the next port 3307... It started, but phpMyAdmin showed the below image:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: see this example do as according to change port   https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-change-the-port-of-a-MySQL-server-in-XAMPP

Comment: @HammadAhmedkhan I did as the webpage said, but it is still wrong.

Comment: kindly use 3308

Comment: @HammadAhmedkhan Why?

Comment: you are not using your port in the browser. You are using port 80. You should do something like this yoururl:3307/...

Comment: @IanChiang may be your port 3307 is also currently in use. possible

Comment: Before you make all kinds of changes, I would figure out what is going on. IIS is a web server, port 3306 is the MySQL database connection port. There's no reason why IIS should be using port 3306, so look at which process is using port 3306 (perhaps with `netstat -a -b` or a tool like TCPView). Don't confuse the port the webserver is using (usually 80, sometimes 8080) with the port MySQL uses (usually 3006); they each use different ports and your web browser wouldn't connect to 3306 nor would you set phpMyAdmin to connect to port 80. So find out what's on 3306 first, then we can move forward.